# DataBinding WPF Image C# ListView SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

Edit:

Problem: 
I'm trying to get information out of a ListBox looking like this: 
When i'm clicking on a row of the listBox i want to save the filepath to a string to use it later. My Problem now is i wont get the filepath with my code, I'think the Problem is that `string filename = listView.SelectedItem.ToString();` takes the whole information out of the listView, the filepath and the status (image).

How do i fill the listView?
Pseudocode:

```
When Button is pressed
-> access xml-file (add filepath to a list)
-> deserelialize it
-> error checking
-> on error
---> add Statusimage to a list
-> update listView.Itemsource = ErrorLog
```

(ErrorLog is my list which holds the Errors and Statusimages)

ErrorLog Class:

```
class ErrorLog
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Log { get; set; }
}
```

How do i get the Filepath from the ListView?

```
private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string filename = listView.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Hope this update is better :)

[MainWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tQ6K.png)

Comment: solved the problem with the image, had to scroll down... *facepalm*

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll down"? Did the image change when you scrolled up and down in your list or was the new row with the expected status just out of view so you had to scroll down?

Comment: I had to scroll down because the images where out of the view. Do you have any idea how i can bind my ListView?

Comment: Please add the definition of `ErrorLog` property and explain what you mean by "*The second Problem i can't read the selectedRow in my ListView*"

Comment: Updated the Question

Comment: Well it's not really matching up... are you sure that your question is actually a single question, where the XAML `listView_SelectionChanged` has anything to do with the C# code `listView_SelectionChanged`? Because I don't see how you can `class ErrorLog` expect to be a filename. Now I don't even know what I would be answering about, so I'm not writing an answer.

Comment: You're right. `class ErrorLog` has nothing to do with my `listView` i could post my whole source code, but it's huge. May I?

Comment: Please don't ;) instead, replace irrelevant parts with pseudo-function-calls a bit like `List<string> myXmlFileNames = GetXmlFileList();` instead of actually giving the whole unrelated loader code in the question. Or even better: provide some static test values to replace unimportant things: `var myXmlFileNames = new string[]{ @"C:\Temp\Test.xml" };`. Hope you get what I mean

Comment: Same with code you already posted: `if (filename.Contains(".xml") == true) { /* I'm happy if I reach this code but it's not happening right now */ }` is enough probably unless the problem is with `XmlDataProvider`.

Comment: Made a Update, hope it's now better to understand. I also added an image of my MainWindow

Comment: So your `Log` (Ereignis) property is the file path for non-status items? Or where is the filepath collection?

Comment: Log contains the current working dir. and the errors which happen in the working dir. 
The filepath comes from my xml deserializer. I'am using a foreach loop to fill the list with filepathes.

Comment: Please be precise... __*which list*__ is filled with your filepaths, show the list definition with exact type so others can understand what is actually expected inside `listView.SelectedItem`.

Comment: Ok, 
T have a list `filePath`it contains all working dirs as strings in this format:
`C:/....../communication.xml` with an foreach loop i go trough all working dir and check if there is an error. At the beginning of my foreach loop i add the current working directory e.g. `C:/......./Client-146/communication.xml` to my `ErrorLog` List. If there is an Error i add the Error as string "Ereignis" and a symbol as "Satus". After the foreach loop and checking about 50 clients i'am filling my ListView with my ErrorLog List, which contains the Ereignis and the Satus. 
Now when i'am clicking

Comment: in the ListView, i want to get the directory which is selected in the ListView.

Comment: So, basically `SelectedItem` is of type `ErrorLog` and you are wondering why `ErrorLog.ToString()` is not a filename... This is why Visual Studio comes with a debugger - just set a breakpoint inside `listView_SelectionChanged` and inspect the variable values

Comment: thats correct, i already have done this. it's not possible to convert type ErrorLog to String. But my question is, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to ignore a whole lot of design issues for now and just focus on the direct question.

I assume `listView.SelectedItem` is of actual type `ErrorLog` and `ErrorLog.Log` contains the file path unless the selected item is a status message with an image.

```
var selectedItem = listView.SelectedItem as ErrorLog;
if (selectedItem != null &&
    string.IsNullOrWhitespace(selectedItem.Status) &&
    File.Exists(selectedItem.Log))
{
    string filename = selectedItem.Log;
}
// else it is a status log entry or something else doesn't match up
```

Comment: God bless ya! Thats it! Thanks a lot! 
`Ok, I'm going to ignore a whole lot of design issues for now and just focus on the direct question.`
Yeah i know, started with wpf a few days ago.. still a lot to learn...